# Solr: Retrieving the query from a QueryResponse

Tags: solr, solrj

Given a QueryResponse object (SolrJ 3.6.2), is there any way to retrieve the query that was made to get that response other than parsing the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryResponse exposes the [Header](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html#getHeader%28%29) information from which the q can be retrieved.

```
rsp.getHeader().get("q")
```

Answer (score 1):

QueryResponse exposes the Header information from which the q can be retrieved. But it cant be directly retrived directly as mentioned by Jayendra.

You need to use:

```
response.getHeader().get("params");
```

This will give you a result like:

```
{start=0,q=apple,qf=name^10.0 description^5.0,version=2,rows=10,defType=edismax}
```

There you can see your result.